# Install Linux in a vhdx on hyper-v in a Windows is secure?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

I have this doubt.

It's known that's Windows has some security issues that Linux doesn't.

If i install some distro in a Hyper-V within Windows but then run this the Linux as a host, configuring the boot via this vhdx, this Linux will get the security issues from Windows, or will be like the Linux is really installed on the host machine?

Comment: You appear to be mixing up "host" and "guest".

Comment: What do you mean? Windows has some security issues that Linux doesn't, but Linux has some security issues that Windows doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of oversimplifying,
if an attacker can gain logical full control of your host (e.g., via network),
it’s equivalent to having full *physical* of any virtual machines
that run on that host. 
They would be able to read and write the VM’s disks. 
Encrypting the disks of the VM might help.

Comment: Understood. But the Windows issues do not apply to the linux, when i'm running the linux as a host, right? It will be like two OS's running side by side installed directly on physical HD of the host?

Comment: I talk here about here about the vulnerabilities that the windows have in a network, if I'm using Linux as a host I don't get these right?